# Can I replace tf.keras.backend with tf?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Implementations in [tf.keras.backend](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend) have duplicates in pure tensorflow. For example: [tf.keras.backend.ones](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/ones) vs [tf.ones](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/ones).

My question: Can I use tensorflow instead of tf.keras.backend, by just replacing it? Both are same API?

Comment: Typically that's the case. you can replace `tf.keras.backend` functions with `tf` functions. I haven't come across an instance where it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use tf but there might be minor difference in the results as both of them have different repo maintained.

For example the [tf.keras.backend.binary_crossentropy](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.1/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L4795-L4831) and [tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.1/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py#L1570-L1605) have different code repo maintained but objective should remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, yes. To learn of the difference, do:

1. `tf.ones?` or `tf.ones??` if your IDE supports it; this'll show docs + source code + file location
2. `from inspect import getsource; print(getsource(tf.ones))` will show source code

I'd not *replace* `K` with `tf`, though; stuff gets moved around between versions, and functionality may break. Each has its own list of imports: `tensorflow/__init__.py` and `tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py`.